Issues with executing PySpark / Delta MERGE statement due to special character in a table name
I am working on implementing CDC (Change Data Capture) which will use Azure Sql as the source and Azure Databricks delta lake as the target.
Azew Sql creates CDC tables with a very specific column names which include special characters: "__$start_lsn" is being one example.
I am having problems executing the following PySpark / Delta "MERGE" statement:
MERGE INTO poc_table_2 AS target
USING cdc_data AS source
ON target.last_processed_lsn = source.__$start_lsn
WHEN MATCHED AND source.__$operation = 1 THEN DELETE
WHEN MATCHED AND source.__$operation IN (3, 4) THEN UPDATE SET *
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT *

In this context, the "source" refers to the Azure Sql cdc table, which I cannot change.
When I run this statement I get this error:
[PARSE_SYNTAX_ERROR] Syntax error at or near '$'. SQLSTATE: 42601
File <command-1987778677957359>, line 40
     30 merge_query = """
     31 MERGE INTO poc_table_2 AS target
     32 USING cdc_data AS source
   (...)
     36 WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT *
     37 """
     39 # Execute the merge query
---> 40 spark.sql(merge_query)
     42 # Update the last processed LSN
     43 last_lsn = cdc_data.agg({"__$start_lsn": "max"}).collect()[0][0]

I have tried using single and double quotes around the column names, but it does not work. When I use quotes, I get a slightly different error:
[PARSE_SYNTAX_ERROR] Syntax error at or near '"__$start_lsn"'. SQLSTATE: 42601

How do I get around this issue?

I have encountred the same ERROR:

The error you are getting is due to the use of special characters (specifically $) in the column names.
In PySpark, when you have column names with special characters, you should use backticks () to enclose the column names.
This tells PySpark to interpret the enclosed string literally, including any special characters it may contain.
I have tried the below approach:
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
from delta.tables import DeltaTable
deltaTablePath = "/FileStore/tables/d01"
if not DeltaTable.isDeltaTable(spark, deltaTablePath):
    (sampleTableDF.withColumn("ID", lit(None).cast("int"))
                  .withColumn("`__$start_lsn`", lit(None).cast("string"))  
                  .withColumn("Name", lit(None).cast("string"))
                  .write
                  .format("delta")
                  .save(deltaTablePath))
deltaTable = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, deltaTablePath)
deltaTable.alias("target") \
    .merge(
        sampleTableDF.alias("source"),
        "target.ID = source.ID"
    ) \
    .whenMatchedUpdate(set = {
        "ID": "source.ID",
        "`__$start_lsn`": "source.`__$start_lsn`",  
        "Name": "source.Name"
    }) \
    .whenNotMatchedInsert(values = {
        "ID": "source.ID",
        "`__$start_lsn`": "source.`__$start_lsn`",  
        "Name": "source.Name"
    }) \
    .execute()

Results:
1   00000021:00000001:0001  Alice
2   00000022:00000002:0002  Bob
3   00000023:00000003:0003  Charlie

